# how to find the file with max date/time inside a zip file having more than one sub directories

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

In a down stream system `Every day` one data folder is created within folder `Data` and files are generated over time within a sub folder `TS` and finally it's zip with name `Data.zip` and uploaded to azure blob by customer.

[image]

[image]

Now I am downloading the zip file and trying to find out the one file which has max date/time. using below code I am able to print all files name inside the zip file, but how to get (print) only the file with max date/time?

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient("conn-string", "upload", "Data.zip");
await DownloadFromStream(blobClient);


public static async Task DownloadFromStream(BlobClient blobClient)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync(new BlobOpenReadOptions(false));
        using ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime))
        {
            if (entry.Name.StartsWith("XXX_TS_"))
            {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried in the below way, and it worked for me.

1. Uploaded the below files to azure container in zip folder.

[image]

In Azure portal.

[image]

Code snippet

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient("ConnectionString", "ContainerName", "Data.zip");
await DownloadFromStream(blobClient);

public static async Task DownloadFromStream(BlobClient blobClient)
        {
            var stream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync(new BlobOpenReadOptions(false));
            ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
            List<string> sFileslist = new List<string>();
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime))
            {
                if (entry.Name.Contains("_TS_"))
                {
                    string[] strFileTokens = entry.Name.Split('_');
                    sFileslist.Add(strFileTokens[2]);
                }   
            }
            string maxValue = sFileslist.Max();
            Console.WriteLine(maxValue);
        }
```

Fetched the Latest file as output.

[image]